# Looping Over Custom Protocol with Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron

I'm currently looping over a custom protocol to pass information into an Electron app from the browser. This works great on every browser except Chrome. The below code runs the protocol in an iframe that then loads the data into Electron.

**Code**

```
<iframe id="dataDiv" style="width:100%;align:center;overflow-y:hidden;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" />

url = "custom-protocol://some-data?"

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $("#dataDiv").attr("src", url + i);
}
```

The above code is pseudo code of how I'm trying to achieve this.

**Expectation**

My expectation is that it will loop 5 times, and pass the data into the Electron app. Like mentioned, this seems to only work with IE and Firefox.

**Actual Results**

While debugging Chrome, I find that it is only executing the first page. From the looks of it, for whatever reason, Chrome is only executing the first protocol load in the loop.

**Other Attempts**

- I've also tried to do a timeout in the loop. Thinking that maybe it's
  just triggering the protocol too fast, and Chrome doesn't like that.
  That failed as well.
- I've even tried just looping over javascript that creates a new tab,
  instead of an iframe.. and it gives me the same result.

Does anyone know of a security setting in Chrome that would prevent custom protocols to be loaded into Chrome multiple times simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple, don't use the protocol to POST data. Instead I ended up creating a web server within electron, and passed the data off via the URL.

```
var http=require('http');
var url=require('url');

var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    var pathname=url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    switch(pathname){
        case '/data':
            var query=url.parse(req.url).query;
            someFunction(query);
            res.end('200 ok');
        break;
    }

}).listen(8080);
```

This way I can use AJAX to launch and hand off data to Electron, instead of iframes.

Then you just pass the data in like:
`http://localhost:8080/data?{insertyourdatahere}`